# Facebook oauth session is null on sending API request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Here is the registration code:

```
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('x','x');
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://xx.com/en/auth/facebooklogin');
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email'
        ));     
        $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper ( 'Redirector' );
        $redirector->gotoUrl ( $loginUrl )->redirectAndExit ();
```

And Here is the redirect code:

```
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('x','x');
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://xx.com/en/auth/facebooklogin');
    $session = null;
    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        Core::session('FacebookAuthSession')->sessionObject = $session;
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {

    } catch(\Exception $ex) {

    }
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

I've read that using the `getLoginUrl` function changes the state however it is being used in a different area than the redirect code so it's not being used more than once.

Here is the error:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given

It should be noted that facebook registration as well as facebook login both initiate with the registration code.